# ajax call request and response is not working below ios 11

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ajax, iphone

I have an ajax call using javascript the ajax call is working fine for android and desktop. But in iOS below iPhone 11 the ajax call is not working but above iPhone 11 it's working fine. I have attached the ajax call below.

```
var inputText = $(this).val();
document.getElementById('suggestions').style.display = 'block';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'suggestions.php?input='+inputText, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        if(xhr.responseText != ''){
            document.getElementById('suggestions').style.height = '150px';
            document.getElementById('suggestions').style.overflowX = 'auto';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('suggestions').style.height = '0';
            document.getElementById('suggestions').style.overflowx = 'none';
        }
        $("#suggestions").html(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

The above code is the ajax call. Where I have ajax call to suggestion.php page with input data.

Comment: Does the browser have any debugging tools to help provide more information, such as an error message or network request/response details?  You need to find out more specific information than "not working".